# Can't we move two tables at the same time in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'd like to place two tables on the left and right and scroll through the left table so that the right table moves together.

Is the above function available on DataTables?
If possible, please give us a simple sample code.

It doesn't seem to be in the Data Tables Document.

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature. I even don't see a use case. If you need the two tables to by synced why not put them in one?

Comment: I am sure this is possible, just very complex. Have you tried asking on the [DataTables Forum?](https://datatables.net/forums/)